# Incorrect string saving on some phone models

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

I created a game on LIBGDX + Android Studio and now testing server, but some phones send the text of the format +XX-XXX-XX-XX-XXX, but should send the text in the format +012345678910

log file:

09 22:40:16 +392700****** correct

09 22:40:23 +XX-XXX-XX-XX-XXX incorrect

Code to save and read String

```
private static Preferences preferences;

public static void set_phone(String str, String val) {
    preferences.putString(str, val);
    preferences.flush();
}

public static String get_phone(String str) {
    return preferences.getString(str);
}
```

Comment: It seems that the `Preferences` class is deprecated in API level 29. If it is the case please have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference).

Comment: Unlikely that API 29 is suddenly saving strings incorrectly just because they deprecated Preferences.

Comment: @AndyGames It's not clear what your problem is. Are you saying that the preferences class is saving a different string from what you passed in? This seems very unlikely. How are you getting the phone number in the first place?